# PHP Login script using Session variables

Tags: php, authentication, session-variables

I created a login form in PHP and after checking the correct username and password from the database, I created a session variable to store the username.

```
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['user']=$user;
  header( "Location: successPage.php" );
```

Thereafter I redirected the user, to the new page. This works perfectly in the `successPage.php` by displaying the username via the `echo` statement. However when I use the following code in other pages, it only displays the PHP code and not the result

```
<?php

    if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){
    echo "<p>You are logged in as ".$_SESSION['user']."</p>";
    echo "<a href='logout.php'>Click here</a>to logout";}

?>
```

Comment: What do you mean, it only displays the PHP code?

Comment: You are logged in as ".$_SESSION['user']; ?> `  is the output

Comment: Did you use `<?php ?>` to enclose your PHP? 'Cause that's what your issue sounds like.

Comment: are the "other" php files and did you use the <?php tags??

Comment: Yes I did use <?php and ?> in between the PHP codes

Comment: did you include session_start() in all other pages?

Comment: Initially yes, thereafter I even tried without that

Comment: could you try post the full code of the page where you echo out the message and the login function?

Answer (score 1):

You need to put `<?php` at the start of the document and `?>` at the end of the document.

However, `?>` at the end of the file is optional.

Therefor, this is valid :

```
<?php

// my page
// blabla

// variables
$Title = 'boom';

?>

<h1><?php echo $Title; ?></h1>

<?php

// I got that boom boom pow
echo $Title;
```

Also, your page's extension must be `.php`. If you are under Windows, be careful. Windows hide file's extension if the option is disabled. If you see a filename `page.php` but you don't see other files extensions, I am afraid your file is in reality `page.php.dotsomething`.

Comment: @Yoosuf The extension of your page is .php ? Are you 110% sure ?

Comment: Yes, thanks one of my files were in .HTML format and eventhough I used the PHP escape characters it still didnt solve the issue. Its working now after changing the extension to .PHP

Comment: Mark the answer as mark please. Always use `.php` to run `php code` even if it's not always true, in your case it will ;)

Answer (score 0):

$_SESSION['user']; ?> ` is the output

get rid of the  `